# Structures within fields

Tags: matlab, structure

```
s = struct('field1',...           
        {
        struct('a',num2cell(0 + 4*rand(5,1)),'b',num2cell(0 + 4*rand(5,1)),'c',0);...
        struct('a',num2cell(0 + 4*rand(5,1)),'b',num2cell(0 + 4*rand(5,1)),'c',0)...
        },...
        'field2',...
        {
        struct('a',num2cell(0 + 4*rand(5,1)),'b',num2cell(0 + 4*rand(5,1)),'c',0);...
        struct('a',num2cell(0 + 4*rand(5,1)),'b',num2cell(0 + 4*rand(5,1)),'c',0)...
        }...
       );
```

How can I loop over structures in each field to avoid listing every structure within a field?

Comment: Fortuitously, Loren has written a blog post on possible [methods for iterating over structures and fields](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2007/08/15/iterating-over-non-numeric-values/).

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
arrayfun( @( w ) structfun( @( x ) arrayfun( @( y ) structfun( @( z ) disp( z ), y ), x ), w ), s )
```

You can replace `disp` with whatever function you wish to apply...

Comment: You can replace `structfun(@(z)disp(z), y)` with `structfun(@disp, y)`, it'll run faster.

Comment: @EitanT - you are definitely right, but I wanted to use `disp` only as a stub for "some user function"...